# How to get the page link from a href="javascript:..."?

Tags: javascript, python, href, screen-scraping

I'm doing web scraping with Python. I need to get links for all the search result pages. However, I found the href value is not a regular html link but something as below. How could I get the right page link? Thanks!

```
<a href="javascript:showDocumentSearchResult('20','20','en','','0', '10','srt', 'docdt', 'desc');">2</a>

<a href="javascript:showDocumentSearchResult('20','40','en','','0', '10','srt', 'docdt', 'desc');">3</a>
```

Comment: where is the code that you mentioned?

Comment: The link you want to see actually is not a hyperlink but more of a javascript function. So you need to `selenium` or some other library which renders the page as well

Comment: Is "2" the href content ? If Yes, this may be related to page number. More description needed here.

Comment: Sorry for not pasting the code correctly. Just edited the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the `showDocumentSearchResult` function in the JS code (it might be in a separate file though). Then knowing what that function does, you might simulate such an action by Python if it's ever possible.

See a following example: https://webscraping.pro/download-a-file-from-a-link-in-python/